# passing echo value from php page to javascript showing junk data

Tags: javascript, php, html

[image: log data]

[image: my php page]

[image: ajax processing]

First image is the log showing value i got in data variable in Ajax success, I'm not able to match it with "success" since returning junk data .
Second image is the page where i enter details in database if my password field both matches(retype password).
Third images is where i get the value from page to Ajax "data" variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if updateprocess.php is only called by this ajax function, then you don't need the `<html>` tag etc, you can get rid of everything before `<?php` and after `?>`...

I would point out the code is extremely open to SQL injection attacks ... so I hope it's for learning purposes only :)

Comment: that worked. so i should not use html tag if it is called by ajax function.? it will be returned along with echo.?

Comment: Correct,,,, HOWEVER... I would recommend that you return JSON it's good practice. It may seem a bit overkill for a success/fail, and you need to parse it at the JS-side. Also... SANITISE anything being inserted into DB... Could be worth at this point suggesting you read up on building a REST API for the AJAX calls. Again don't know you're project but would be very worthwhile learning.